# How do you find out which NPM modules depend on yours?

Tags: node.js, module, dependencies, npm

It's easy to see what modules a specific module depends on but I can't seem to find out how to see what modules depend on a specific module. Is there a simple way to do this? If so, is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Are you talking about globally on NPM, or for your specific application?

Comment: Globally on NPM. I'd like to specify any specific module and determine what other modules depend on it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Update:** The registry API has changed, and may or may not let you talk directly to underlying CouchDB database. Fortunately, there is still a public mirror provided for replication at https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry that you can still send queries to. To use:

```
https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/_design/app/_view/dependedUpon?group_level=3&startkey=%5B"socket.io"%5D&endkey=%5B"socket.io"%2C%7B%7D%5D&skip=0&limit=1000
```

For ease of reading, here are the querystring parameters from the example:

```
{ group_level: 3,
  startkey: '["socket.io"]',
  endkey: '["socket.io", {}]',
  skip: 0,
  limit: 1000 }
```

Note that as stated above, these are parameters for a CouchDB request. There doesn't seem to be an endpoint on the official API to get this data, but there's an issue open for the registry that you can follow [here](https://github.com/npm/registry/issues/231).

---

The closest thing you'd get to doing that is probably requesting JSON from the npm registry. For example, to get the packages dependent on Socket.IO, send a `GET` request to this link:

```
http://registry.npmjs.org/-/_view/dependedUpon?group_level=3&startkey=%5B%22socket.io%22%5D&endkey=%5B%22socket.io%22%2C%7B%7D%5D&skip=0&limit=1000
```

Comment: I can't get this to work with a locally hosted NPM registry. I get back `{ "error" : "no such package available" }`. Would be awesome if you could explain the URL parameters, or at least link to the API docs which describe them.

Comment: @BenBurns It is [a CouchDB query](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/views.html).

Comment: @Chev is there any documentation for the npm registry API?

Comment: @caesarsol That is a CouchDB query actually, which is what backs the npm registry. So the [CouchDB](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/) API documentation is what you're after.

Comment: This times out on me with "Error 503 first byte timeout". Is that because there are too many dependents?

Comment: @rustyx Changed registry location to CouchDB replicate - give that a go?

Comment: I tried it to find dependents of `@sourcegraph/react-loading-spinner`, which shows one dependent on the [dependents page](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/@sourcegraph/react-loading-spinner).
I used this query URL: https://npm-skimdb.sourcegraph.com/registry/_design/app/_view/dependedUpon?group_level=3&startkey=%5B%22%40sourcegraph%2Freact-loading-spinner%22%5D&endkey=%5B%22%40sourcegraph%2Freact-loading-spinner%22%2C%7B%7D%5D&limit=100&skip=0
But it returns 0 rows. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `The API was deprecated`

Answer (score 23):

You can browse them on npmjs.com itself, by going to a URLs like, for example, https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/markdown-it

Answer (score 14):

As of lately there is also https://libraries.io/npm/socket.io that tracks dependents and dependencies for you.

Comment: Love this because it also track dev dependencies which npm doesn't!

Comment: Awesome. It has a http API.

Answer (score 4):

dependedUpon is wrapped by at least these tools now :

```
npm install -g npm-static-stats dependents-tree npm-get-dependents npm-dependents
```

dependents-tree looks most useful for checking out a new package