# Find what NPM modules depend on yours in a local Verdaccio registry

Tags: node.js, npm, module, dependencies

Previously, a [similar question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796890/how-do-you-find-out-which-npm-modules-depend-on-yours). However, this question never received an answer that addressed attempting to complete the same task on a local Verdaccio repo. As Ben Burns noted in the comments, making the API call used in the highest rated answer will only result in the server returning `{ "error" : "no such package available" }`.

Is there a way to find dependents on a local Verdaccio registry? And if so, how?

Comment: What kind of local registry?

Comment: @ralphtheninja [Verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio)

Comment: Hi, I'm verdaccio maintainer. Unfortunately I think there is no such thing implemented yet, but I'd recommend file a ticket seems a good idea.